# Why is ANTLR C# autogenerated parser not matching EOF?

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr

I have a very simple grammar that (I think) should only allow additions of two elements like `1+1` or `2+3`

```
grammar dumbCalculator;
expression: simple_add EOF;
simple_add: INT ADD INT;

INT:('0'..'9');
ADD : '+';
```

I generate my C# classes using the official ANTLR jar file

```
java -jar "antlr-4.9-complete.jar" C:\Users\Me\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\dumbCalculator.g4 -o C:\Users\Me\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\Dumb -Dlanguage=CSharp -no-listener -visitor
```

No matter what I try, the parser keeps adding the trailing elements although they shouldn't be allowed.

For example `"1+1+1"` gets parsed properly as an AST :

```
expression
    simple_add
        1
        +
        1
    +
    1
```

Although I specifically wrote that `expression` must be `simple_add` then `EOF` and `simple_add` is just `INT ADD INT`. I have no idea why the rest is being accepted, I expect ANTLR to throw an exception on this.

This is how I test my parser :

```
var inputStream = new AntlrInputStream("1+1+1");
var lexer = new dumbCalculatorLexer(inputStream);
lexer.RemoveErrorListeners();
lexer.AddErrorListener(new ThrowExceptionErrorListener());
var commonTokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
var parser = new dumbCalculatorParser(commonTokenStream);
parser.RemoveErrorListeners();
parser.AddErrorListener(new ThrowExceptionErrorListener());
var ex = parser.expression();
ExploreAST(ex);
```

**Why is the rest of the output being accepted ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classical scenario, I find my error 5 minutes after posting on Stack Overflow.

For anyone encountering a similar scenario, this happened because I did not explicitly set the `ErrorHandler` on my parser.

Naively, I expected all the `AddErrorListener` to handle the errors, but somehow there's a specific thing to do if you need the errors to be handled before visiting the tree.

I needed to add

```
parser.ErrorHandler = new BailErrorStrategy();
```

After this, I indeed got the exceptions on wrong input strings.

This is probably not the right thing to do, I'll let someone who knows ANTLR better to comment on this.